# oracle discoverer 11g error for dates ORA-00920 Invalid relational operator

Tags: oracle

I have lot of queries as below

```
  WHERE   ( (o215251.MS_SUB_ACNT_CODE = o215225.TD_SUB_ACNT_CODE(+)
          AND o215251.MS_MAIN_ACNT_CODE = o215225.TD_MAIN_ACNT_CODE(+)))
       AND (o215225.STATUS(+) = 'P')
       AND (o215225.TD_MAIN_ACNT_CODE(+) = '989898'
            AND o215251.MS_MAIN_ACNT_CODE = '989898')
       AND ( (o215225.DOC_DATE)(+) BETWEEN :FromDate AND :ToDate)
```

In Oracle Discoverer 10g, I have no problem running these types of queries, but we were testing Oracle Discoverer 11g and always get an error for these types of queries:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.

If I remove the date filter, the query runs perfect.

I cannot change the queries, it is nearly impossible.

Any other solution, some registry tweak?

Comment: Can you see how Oracle rewrites the query for execution under both platforms, and what the bind parameters are actually being set to? If the rewritten SQL is in fact in valid in 11g then you should probably raise a service request with Oracle. Would be interesting to see if it works with ANSI outer joins though, rather than Oracle's old `(+)` syntax.

Comment: @AlexPoole, i got it solved by applying oracle patch no 10277316.

Comment: The above code which I have posted is how oracle discoverer rewrites the query when date parameter is added to discoverer.

Comment: OK, that's good. You can add what you had to do as an answer and accept that - better to have the patch reference and the simple description as an answer rather than just a comment, so that anyone else with the same issue can easily see how to make the same change you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AlexPoole, i got it solved by applying oracle patch no 10277316.